# ¿ Como evitar que se dupliquen registros al insertar en una tabla?

Tags: mysql

Tengo esta tabla en mi base de datos:

```
    create table caja
   (
   Operación int auto_increment,
   Caja int  not null,
   Fecha date not null,
   Ingreso real(19,2) not null,
   Egreso real(19,2) not null,
   Pesos real(19,2) not null,
   Dolares int not null,
   Euros int not null,
   Moneda int not null,
   Primary key(operación, caja)
   )
```

En algún momento al hacer las operaciones correspondientes e insertar registros, los mismos se duplican..
Por ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al realizar un ingreso de 400 pesos resulta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

'operacion' es el numero que se genera automaticamente por cada operación y moenda representa los pesos(1), dolares(2) y euros(3).

Antes se realizaron las operaciones para actualizar los campos con el nuevo dato que se va a insertar.. si antes tenia 500 pesos, con los 400 ingresados debería resultar 900.. Esa seria la operación previa.
El codigo que utilizo para insertar es el siguiente:

```
include('conexion.php');
// cantidad ingresada por teclado.
$cantidad = $_post['cantidad'];
$query = "SELECT pesos from caja 
   where moneda = 1 
   and caja = 5 
   and fecha = '2021-06-24' 
   order by operacion desc limit 1"; 

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); 
$datos = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
$datos_pesos = $datos['pesos'];

if($datos_pesos <> []){
   $pesos = $datos_pesos + $cantidad;
}
else $pesos = $cantidad;
  
insert ignore into caja values
('',5,'2021-06-24','$cantidad',0,'$pesos',0,0,1);
```

Comment: ese insert no tiene nada pero nada que ver con tu tabla.. ahi hay 2 valores 400 que no estan reflejados en la tabla... tendras alguna clase de trigger sobre la tabla? y porque haces insert ignore...

Comment: Buenos días, acabo de editar la pregunta.  Puse el código que utilizo para realizar la operación previa a insertar.. ahora no se si estoy estoy haciendo uso correcto de Insert Ignore o debería hacer solo un Insert??  en otra ocasión también se duplicaron los registros al hacer solo un Insert.  Me podrías ayudar?

Comment: los insert no duplican registros.. si se te duplican registros, es por otro motivo... aca no se ve nada malo... estaras llamando este codigo mas de una vez... escribi alguna clase de log para comprobarlo....

Comment: el código que hace el ingreso e inserción se llama ingreso.php, a ese código le envió datos por Ajax y solo envió los datos cuando se presiona un botón para confirmar la operación de ingreso de pesos , dólares o euros.  Tendrá algo que ver el  archivo js que invoca al ingreso.php ?

Comment: ni idea.. pero una query no inserta multiples registros...